# Is Redux an alternate to Sessions, Cookies or is a persistant database?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, sysdatabases

I want to know if redux has its own database or need MongoDB, MySQL or other databases?

Is it the alternate to sessions, cookies, internalStorage, LocalStorage and IndexedDB?

Is redux the best way to pass the states/data between react components?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Redux is for client state, by default it's in-memory only, though there is nothing stopping you from persisting it to localStorage, sessionStorage or indexedDB. It is not a 1:1 mapping to your database data, or at least that's not how most people use it. It is for your views to dispatch actions and then update the store state so other views can react to those data changes.

People use it in combination with a backend, for example your action can be a function which fetches or puts data via an API to a database, and you can store the results in your store by dispatching actions on success or failure.

Answer (score 1):

Redux is an in-memory store that keeps track of data from various places throughout your application and helps you route that data to where it needs to go. It does not involve a traditional, persistent database. In fact, using a database to persist the Redux state would be quite unusual, since the type of data typically stored in Redux is usually related to a particular user and a particular session. That is, things like, "The user has clicked button A." Most apps only need to remember that while the user is logged in and still on a given page.

That said, there is no particular reason why you couldn't save the Redux state in a database if you want your app's state to be maintained permanently. I think most UX designers would say that is unnecessary, though, and even potentially confusing depending on the complexity of the app, the number of views the app has, and how long it has been since a user last logged in.